# AngularJS Filter causing a $digest cycle errors

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to get some graphing working with ng and d3, just having issues with digest cycle warnings.

I have a directive that does the graphing for me, and I want to filter the data when my checkboxes (that are bound to the same data) are changed.

This is the filter that I'm using:

```
<div data-d3-line data-chart-data="vm.chartData | filter:{show:true}" data-data-updated="vm.dataUpdated"></div>
```

If the filter is removed, the binding happens, no errors.  I'm sure this is something simple that I'm overlooking, but it's one of those pull your hair out moments.

I put together this plunker in hopes of getting a hand:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5QVOvNKw0AqEogihcdyO

P.S. I know that I'm using a poor man's eventing with that dataUpdated watch.  I was originally watching the vm.chartData, and thought that caused the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter can't be used with a two-way binding `=` of an isolated scope.

This is because in the two-way binding, the expression will be watched for an identity change. But everytime the expression is evaluated, the filter will produce a different (in identity) array, thus a digest cycle will go into a loop.

To solve this problem, it depends on how you use the `vm.chartData`.

If the d3 directive don't need to update and sync the `chartData` back to parent. One solution is to not use the two-way binding and manually watch the expression instead. For example:

```
var directive = {
  scope: {
    data: '&chartData' // use & instead of = here
  },
  link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('data()', function (newData) {
      Update(angular.copy(newData));
    }, true); // watch for equality, not identity (deep watch)
  }
};
```

Or if each item of `chartData` will not be changed, may be using `$watchCollection` is enough.

```
scope.$watchCollection('data()', function (newData) {
  Update(angular.copy(newData));
});
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/0xArS1VAbZCwOpo4VYrw?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was quite helpful.  I have to mess about with my D3 update method, but you sorted out exactly what I needed.  Cheers.